# How to connect to another instance of Sql Server with different version in Sql Server 2008 Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have stored procedure in a database in an instance of `Sql Server 2008`.

I have a stored procedure that inside of it I want to connect to a `Sql Server 2005` database with `UserName` and `Password` and Insert some data to a table.

How I can Do this?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a linked server. You cannot do this in the context of a stored procedure. You can however setup the login credentials in a stored procedure. In the example below it assumes that the linked server was named OTHERSERVER. This would allow you to pass a user name and password for the new connection and call a stored procedure.

```
create procedure NewTestProc (
    @I int,
    @userName sysname,
    @password   sysname
)
as
begin
    declare @locallogin sysname
    set @locallogin = SUSER_NAME()

    EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
        @rmtsrvname=N'OTHERSERVER', @useself=N'False',
        @locallogin=@locallogin,@rmtuser=@userName,
        @rmtpassword=@password
    EXEC OTHERSERVER.DestinationDatabase.dbo.StoredProcInOtherDatabase 
        @OtherParameter = @i
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_droplinkedsrvlogin
        @rmtsrvname=N'OTHERSERVER',@locallogin=@locallogin
end
```

To call a stored procedure you would also have to enable RPC for the linked server

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'OTHERSERVER', 
     @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'true'
```

Answer (score 1):

Create linked server. In SSMS go to "Server Objects"->"Linked Servers" and create New Linked Server for Sql2005 instance providing security context you want to use. Then in the SP refer to the Sql2005 table as: [linked server name].[database name].[schema name].[table name]